# gdb could not be started - DDD to a remote inferior debugger

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger, rsh, inetd

Im trying to attach DDD to gdb on a remote machine. I have configured rsh to not require a pass for my machine & username.

ddd opens with "rtx5:1234: not found" and a pop-up with "GDB could not be started". From calling ddd --host rtx5:2159 --trace --no-exec-window /home/murray/beer-process

```
#  Running GDB (pid 2826, tty /dev/pts/1)...
#  Current language: C/C++
#  Searching "vsllib/ddd.vsl"...
#  Trying "/home/murray/.ddd/vsllib/ddd.vsl"
#  Trying "/usr/share/ddd-3.3.12/vsllib/ddd.vsl"
#  Searching "vsllib/ddd.vsl"..."/usr/share/ddd-3.3.12/vsllib/ddd.vsl".
<- "sh: line 0: exec: rtx5:2159: not found\n"
#  Running GDB (pid 2826, tty /dev/pts/1)...Exit 127.
```

The PID of GDB started by ddd from the trace logs are 4-digits. However, all the PIDs that I can see from the rtx(target) are 8-digit. I can not see gdb as a process yet the trace log indicates otherwise. Is the documentation out of date and I am invoking it incorrectly? How could I test if ddd is correctly rsh-ing?

I have addressed the caveats of the [docs 2.4.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/pdf/ddd.pdf):

- Beer-process binary is in the home dir of my username on the target.
- Checked the path of gdb in /usr/bin/gdb
- rtx5 does not have xterm therefore include --no-exec-window flag

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you did some research on your own, please share it too. If you try to do something first and ask more specific questions, your post will be more welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Had a firewall on the host interfering only with ddd's rsh connection. I also had to substitute "rtx5" for "'rsh rtx5'". It wont find the program I pass it, even though its in the home directory of the remote target. I can however use ddd-gui to find, load, and debug it.

I could rsh to rtx5 without a password, then call gdb. 
I could not do "rsh rtx5 gdb" and have gdb start.  This is due to [rsh](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3077223). When rsh is called without a command it operates out of 514. If rsh in called with a command it communicates and attempts to move to a different port number. This is where my firewall was blocking it.
Wireshark showed me from local to target after rsh connection:

```
destination unreachable (host administratively protected)
```

ddd still has issues primarily that I can not load a binary which is in my remote home directory. This extends problem extends to attaching to running processes on the remote host. In both cases I can load/connect via the gui once the connection is established.
Furthermore I have to call ddd with 'rsh ' prepended to the remote-host name. This seems wrong. I'll update when I have more.